# Ray local cluster web-ui shows 0 workers

Tags: python, ray

Launching the ray head node with web-ui:

```
ray start --head --redis-port=6379 --include-webui --num-cpus=0
```

when I navigate to the UI (after I start training) I don't see any workers being used.

Can someone confirm that this works for them?

Thanks.[image]

Comment: The UI is very preliminary and it doesn't show much information yet. It will be improved a lot in the near future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the ui today (Aug, 2019). The docs are outdated with the UI pictures it seems.

Just in case anyone in the future has similar question.